# Table is not being created using SQLite in Android application

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I try to create a table using sqlite in my application.

Here is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_USAGE = "total_usage";


    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," 
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TOTAL_USAGE + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At
    //    values.put(KEY_TOTAL_USAGE, total_usage); // Total_usage

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);

        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void updateUser(String email, String total_usage) {
        String selectQuery = "UPDATE login SET total_usage = 132 WHERE email = 'sampleMail'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL(selectQuery);

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.close(); 
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

My question is: Why is table `login` never created? Am I doing something wrong? It couldnt be this hard to solve a problem like this. Im encountering much difficulties using Sqlite. It would be nice if someone could help me. Im using phpmyadmin as database

The application itself gives no erros, logcat is empty

And I deleted and run the application billion times, but it did not work

Maybe this information is usefull: When I type adb in terminal, it is not recognized.

why is onCreate() method never called? Forgive me If I misuse some terms as I am getting crazy by not solving this issue for 1 week :(

I used this in my code: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

---

The code below did not worked:

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until you call the method getWritableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase() of SQLiteOpenHelper class, database won't be created.

What you can do is store a variable field 
`SQLiteDatabase db;`
and then in the constructor call `db = db.getWriteableDatabase()/readable();`

I think this will solve your problem :)

Edit: Try this:

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void open(){
     db = getWritableDatabase();
}
```

And then do something like this:

```
DatabaseHandler dh = new DatabaseHandler();
dh.open()
```

If this still doesn't work, try 
https://www.google.se/?gws_rd=ssl#q=android+sqlite+oncreate+not+called

Good luck!

Comment: Please correct me if Im wrong, but I am already doing that in updateUser() function.

Comment: Did you try calling getWriteable in constructor? When calling getWriteable/readable for the first time on a new device, onCreate should be called, onUpgrade is called if the db version number is changed. So, even thought you re-upload the app from your ide to your phone, onCreate will only be called once, the first time you upload the app.

Comment: Could you write the code please (or where I have to put the code)? Normally I dont ask directly for the code, but this issue wasted 1 week for me

Comment: try putting getWriteableDatabase() in your constructor DatabaseHandler. Come back if that doesn't solve it ;)

Comment: Did not work. I would be realy grateful if you could help me solving this problem sir

Comment: Did not work, sorry. Maybe it has something to do with php files? I use a domain x.com/android_login_api